# Insert $ before and after equation using Lyx

Tags: math-mode, lyx

I use Mathstackexchange frequently and usually I write down my question on Lyx and then copy to the website. However, I must insert a $ sign before and after every equation while I am writing it down with Lyx. Is there a smart way to do this without inserting it every time? Thank you.
Here's how it looks like. As you can see I want to insert a $ symbol everytime.[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What do you mean? A keyboard shortcut, leaving it out completely?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, exactly. I don't know if for example Lyx has some kind of built-in function that everytime I initialize an equation it would insert those "$" signs. As far as I know there's something called macros but I don't know if this would solve my problem.

Comment: Do you start all your equations the same way? How should Lyx know when math starts other than `$`? I do not really get it, but maybe there are some Lyx experts who can manage it. (Btw: Macros could also refer to TeX commands.)

Comment: I don't know absolutely anything about Latex except using Lyx. When you want to insert an equation on Lyx you simple press CRTL + M. I will attach a photo to my post.

Comment: I don't get it either. I use LyX sometimes and in that case I don't need to introduce those `$` myself. Entering math inline mode is enough (the CTRL+M shortcut you speak of).

Comment: My problem is the following: I wrote a line on Lyx and I copied here: "By the first isomorphim theorem for modules, S/(S\cap T)\simeq(S+T)/T."
Since I didn't use $"equation"$ the symbols did not appear... It is a bit tedious to insert these symbols everytime I have to copy them to stackexchange.

Comment: I think this post answers my question: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17081/using-lyx-to-write-answers-for-posts

Comment: Enter math mode for your equations, and once inside this mode, each time you want to insert a symbol like `\cap` or `\simeq`, use the `Insert/TeX Code` menu (ctrl-L shortcut, I think). But you could also use one of the numerous LyX math symbols tables.

Comment: The reason is that when you copy in LyX, LyX thinks you want to copy it as text. What you really want is to copy the LaTeX. To do this, you can either go to File > Export > LaTeX (pdflatex), or you can go to View > Code Preview Pane and copy the LaTeX from there.

Comment: @scottkosty, now I understood. And your tips solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort answer: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> already insert `$ $` in LaTeX code.

Long answer:

In LaTeX `$` is an active character that start/end the inline math mode.
In Lyx,  `$` is not a active character that will do nothing except print that symbol, and it will we exported to LaTeX as`\$` (the inactive symbol)  in text mode or in math mode.

Therefore you cannot  write in LyX `$...$` to make an equation like in LaTeX, except if you are in a TeX box, aka Evil Red Tex (ERT), using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> but then you must work with LateX code in the red box, that do not show anything except what you write. Be careful with ERTs, some typo here can produce a fatal error (= no PDF preview).

To write in math mode in LyX use the blue ∑ butttom or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>. This make a blue box,  warning you that a  math environment equivalent to `$...$` in LaTeX is already done,  then you can write the equation with LaTeX commands as `\simeq` but is showed the correspondent symbol `≃`.

You can also write the equation "as is" in text mode (e.g.: `A \simeq B`), then select the equation with the cursor and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to convert to math mode (i.e.,`A≃B`).

But as show your screenshot, all you equations are already in math mode, so you are trying is not only wrong, but also absolutely unnecessary.